# Issues using telnet in a function causing code scaling issues python

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

So I am having some code scaling problems in my VLAN script.

Basically I have a function addvlanfunc() that will:

1. telnet into a switch
2. create a vlan
3. exit the telnet session
4. close the telnet session
5. This process repeats on all switches
6. A for loop causes this to repeat until all VLANS have been configured

Everything works properly but I can see some scaling issues. So I would like to put another function in my code that would take the commands that are being ran on the switches that never change and put them in a one line function called vlancmd()  for addvlanfunc() to call.

However When I do this I can only add the first VLAN in my list to the first switch and my code errors out with a message about telnet closing. the entire error is below, next is the working code, and after that is the broken code. I guess I want to know what I am breaking when I try to use this new function. I appreciate any insight that can be given to me!
(my traceback might be slightly off I changed some variable values to protect the innocent)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "WF-VLAN-AUTO-FOR-FUNC-TEST", line 70, in <module>
        addvlanfunc()
      File "WF-VLAN-AUTO-FOR-FUNC-TEST", line 27, in addvlanfunc
        vlancmd()
      File "WF-VLAN-AUTO-FOR-FUNC-TEST", line 9, in vlancmd
        tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
      File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\telnetlib.py", line 327, in read_until
        return self.read_very_lazy()
      File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\telnetlib.py", line 403, in read_very_lazy
        raise EOFError('telnet connection closed')
    EOFError: telnet connection closed
```

```py
    #GOOD CODE BELOW

    import getpass
    import sys
    import telnetlib

    # Defines a function that will add vlans to catalyst switches

    def addvlanfunc():
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
        tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
        tn.write(teluser.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        if telpassword:
            tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
            tn.write(telpassword.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
            tn.write(b"enable\n")
            tn.write(enpassword.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
            tn.write(b"conf t\n")
            tn.write(b"vlan " + vlans.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
            tn.write(b"end\n")
            tn.write(b"exit\n")
            print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))
            tn.close()
            tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST1)
            tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
            tn.write(teluser.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
            if telpassword:
                tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
                tn.write(telpassword.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
                tn.write(b"enable\n")
                tn.write(enpassword.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
                tn.write(b"conf t\n")
                tn.write(b"vlan " + vlans.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
                tn.write(b"end\n")
                tn.write(b"exit\n")
                print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))
                tn.close()

    # Defines a function that will remove a vlan on a catalyst switch
    def rmvvlanfunc():
        tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
        tn.write(teluser.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        if telpassword:
            tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
            tn.write(telpassword.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
            tn.write(b"enable\n")
            tn.write(enpassword.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
            tn.write(b"conf t\n")
            tn.write(b"no vlan " + vlantoremove.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
            tn.write(b"end\n")
            tn.write(b"exit\n")
            print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))



    HOST = "x.x.x.x"
    HOST1 = "y.y.y.y"
    teluser = "username"
    telpassword = "telpassword"
    enpassword = "enpassword"
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
    # Host variables define a switch that will be configured
    # teluser and password are the credentals that will be used to telnet into switch
    # enable password will allow user to configure switch
    # tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST) this variable needs changed everytime we need to run the function on the next switch



    print("WELCOME TO WF VLAN AUTOMATION")
    print("0.Exit")
    print("1.Create a VLAN")
    print("2.Remove a VLAN")
    userchoice = input("Please make a choice: ")
    # Core of script is in the if, elif, and else statements
    # user choice will allow functions to be ran on switches and easy input validation

    if userchoice == "0":
        exit()

    elif userchoice == "1":
        vlantoadd = input("Please enter VLANS: ").split()
        for vlans in vlantoadd:
            addvlanfunc()



    else:
        exit()


    #BAD CODE BELOW

    import getpass
    import sys
    import telnetlib


    # Defines a function that will add vlans to catalyst switches

    def vlancmd():
        tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
        tn.write(teluser.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        if telpassword:
            tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
            tn.write(telpassword.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
            tn.write(b"enable\n")
            tn.write(enpassword.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
            tn.write(b"conf t\n")
            tn.write(b"vlan " + vlans.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
            tn.write(b"end\n")
            tn.write(b"exit\n")
            print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))

    def addvlanfunc():
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
        vlancmd()
        tn.close()
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST1)
        vlancmd()
        tn.close()

    # Defines a function that will remove a vlan on a catalyst switch
    def rmvvlanfunc():
        tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
        tn.write(teluser.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        if telpassword:
            tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
            tn.write(telpassword.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
            tn.write(b"enable\n")
            tn.write(enpassword.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
            tn.write(b"conf t\n")
            tn.write(b"no vlan " + vlantoremove.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
            tn.write(b"end\n")
            tn.write(b"exit\n")
            print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))

    HOST = "x.x.x.x"
    HOST1 = "y.y.y.y"
    teluser = "teluser"
    telpassword = "telpassword"
    enpassword = "enpassword"
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
    # Host variables define a switch that will be configured
    # teluser and password are the credentals that will be used to telnet into switch
    # enable password will allow user to configure switch
    # tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST) this variable needs changed everytime we need to run the function on the next switch

    print("WELCOME TO WF VLAN AUTOMATION")
    print("0.Exit")
    print("1.Create a VLAN")
    print("2.Remove a VLAN")
    userchoice = input("Please make a choice: ")
    # Core of script is in the if, elif, and else statements
    # user choice will allow functions to be ran on switches and easy input validation

    if userchoice == "0":
        exit()

    elif userchoice == "1":
        vlantoadd = input("Please enter VLANS: ").split()
        for vlans in vlantoadd:
            addvlanfunc()

    else:
        exit()
```

Comment: The `tn` that you assign inside `addvlanfunc()` is a *local variable*.  `vlancmd()` has no access to it, and should probably be receiving it as a parameter.